# Java 2Dimensional String array: find column where all elements are the same

Tags: java, arrays, string, for-loop, 2d

I'm pretty sure the question is already asked but I can't seem to find a solution that helps me solve my problem.

I got a 2dimensional string array.

```
String[][] available = new String[10][15];
```

The array contains the words : ok and no with a tab between each element. This is how it looks :

```
ok  ok  no  ok  ok  no  ok  ok  ok  no  no  no  ok  ok  ok
ok  no  ok  no  ok  ok  ok  no  ok  ok  no  ok  ok  no  ok
ok  ok  ok  ok  no  no  no  no  no  ok  no  ok  ok  no  ok
ok  no  ok  ok  no  no  no  no  no  ok  no  ok  ok  no  ok
no  no  ok  ok  no  no  no  no  no  ok  no  ok  ok  ok  ok
ok  ok  ok  ok  no  ok  no  no  no  ok  no  ok  ok  no  ok
```

Now there are mutiple columns where the entire column is filled with ok.
I actually only need the first column where each element is ok.

The string might be extended later so I will need it in a for loop with .length
This code prints out correct columns but the problem is this wil not work when the array is extended :

```
    for (int r =0; r < 10; r++){
        for (int k = 0; k < 15; k++){
            if ( "ok" == poll[r +0][k] && 
                 "ok" == poll[r +1][k] &&
                 "ok" == poll[r +2][k] &&
                 "ok" == poll[r +3][k] && 
                 "ok" == poll[r +4][k] &&
                 "ok" == poll[r +5][k] &&
                 "ok" == poll[r +6][k] &&
                 "ok" == poll[r +7][k] &&
                 "ok" == poll[r +8][k] &&
                 "ok" == poll[r +9][k] ){
                System.out.println(k);
            }            
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
int columnNumber = -1;    

for (int column = 0; column < available.length; column++) {

    boolean columnYes = true;        

    for (int row = 0; row < available.length; row++) {
        if (!available[row][column].equals("yes")) {
            columnYes = false;
        }
    }

    if (columnYes) {
        columnNumber = column;
        break;
    }
}
```

This code will search for the **first** column where all elements are `"yes"` and return its **index**, for the column **number** write `columnNumber = column + 1;`. if there is **no such column** you get `-1`. Keep in mind that your columns must all be **equal in size** (as I understood from your question) for the code above to work.

You should also consider making your array `boolean[]` or an `enum` `Choice[]` and return a `String` based on its value in a separate function, instead of storing the same strings over and over, which consumes much memory and cannot be changed easily. Furthermore, comparing strings in this case does only cost performance unnecessarily.

Comment: The column number resembles a date where everyone is available. And i need the first date where everyone is available. So I indeed only need the first column

Comment: Sorry i'm quite new at programming, i do not understand how I could retrieve the column where all elements equal "yes".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understood your problem but this should work (although there's probably a better algorithm for this task).

```
int counter = 0;

for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < 15; col++) {
        if (available[row][col].equals("ok") == false) break;
        else counter++;
    }

    if (counter == 15) return row;
}

return -1; // no row has *all* columns set to "yes"
```

If you want to count the lines in which this happens (and not the first line), just add an extra counter and return it at the end.

Although, like @thatguy said, you should be better off using a boolean matrix.

Comment: What does the break do?

Comment: This wil output the column were all elements are " no" to. I actually need the ones with ok only.

Comment: You haven't very clear regarding the original problem but what that method should do is iterate over the matrix and return the first index of the row on which all of its columns are "yes" (or "ok" or w/e).

Comment: The break breaks the second for cycle if it detects a "no".